# Strange behaviour with Fragment UI on load

Tags: android, android-fragments

Okay, so I have a Android App that uses the built in NavigationDrawer Activity with Fragments for each view. One of the views pulls some data from a web service, but since the data doesn't change during a single day I store the values in the preferences as well as a timestamp for the day the tab was opened so that web service method isn't called every time the user opens that tab. The problem that I'm having though is that when the timestamp section just moves to the part of the code that updates the view some items aren't being drawn correctly (some are squished down while others aren't showing the correct placement on the screen). If I click the refresh button to call the web service methods and then update the view that way it always draws them correctly. I don't know where I'm messing up, but I'm sure it's me since Android is pretty new to me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales, container, false);

    thisActivity = this.getActivity();

    mtdHeaderTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdHeaderText);
    mtdSeekBar = (SeekBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdSeekBar);
    mtdTopSeekBar = (SeekBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdTopSeekBar);
    mtdValueTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdValueTextView);
    mtdGoalTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdGoalTextView);
    mtdDateTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mtdDateTextView);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CheckTimeStamp();
}

public static void CheckTimeStamp() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = HelperClass.PreferenceFileName(thisActivity);
    String timeStamp = preferences.getString(Constants.keySalesTimeStamp, "");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    String currentTime = HelperClass.GetSimpleDateFormat(date);
    if (currentTime.equals(timeStamp)) {
        foundMTDValue = preferences.getString(Constants.keyMTDValue, "");
        foundYTDValue = preferences.getString(Constants.keyYTDValue, "");
        UpdateMTDProgress();-->this is the method that adds values to the textviews and seekbars
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.keySalesTimeStamp, currentTime);
        editor.apply();
        GetMTDValue(); -->this calls the web service to get values and then calls UpdateMTDProgress like above
    }
}
```

Below is the code from the UpdateMTDProgres section

```
public static void UpdateMTDProgress() {
    //First update Header Text View
    SharedPreferences preferences = HelperClass.PreferenceFileName(thisActivity);
    int mtdGoal = preferences.getInt(Constants.keyMonthlyGoal, 0);
    double percentage = Double.parseDouble(foundMTDValue) / mtdGoal;
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    String percentageString = format.format(percentage);
    mtdHeaderTextView.setText("MTD Commissions (" + percentageString + ")");
    //Get Current Date and Number of Days in Month
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int totalDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //Get Daily Goal for Rep based on mtdGoal and number of days
    int dailyGoal = mtdGoal/totalDays;
    //Get current day goal
    int currentDayGoal = dailyGoal * currentDay;
    //Check if current mtd value against currentdaygoal
    if (Double.parseDouble(foundMTDValue) >= currentDayGoal) {
        mtdSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(thisActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_green));
    }
    else {
        mtdSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(thisActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_red));
    }
    //update progress seekbar values
    mtdSeekBar.setMax(mtdGoal);
    mtdSeekBar.setProgress((int) Double.parseDouble(foundMTDValue));
    //update indicator seekbar values
    mtdTopSeekBar.setMax(totalDays);
    mtdTopSeekBar.setProgress(currentDay);
    //Update Current Value and Goal TextViews
    String currentValueString = HelperClass.ConvertStringToCurrency(foundMTDValue);
    mtdValueTextView.setText(currentValueString);
    String goalValueString = HelperClass.ConvertStringToCurrency(String.valueOf(mtdGoal));
    mtdGoalTextView.setText(goalValueString);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
    String shortDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    mtdDateTextView.setText(shortDate);
```

Comment: Can you please show your `UpdateMTDProgress()` method?

Comment: I added the code from the Update method.

Comment: Just an advice, next time you post code, can you make it a little more readable? Like, better formatted?